# rounding double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android

i need to output e4 and e5 to 2 decimal places as it is currency

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                                          
        if (e2.getText().toString() != "")                                              
        {                                                                               
            double salePrice = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());             
            double ebayFee = salePrice / 10.00;                                         
            double paypalFee = (salePrice * 0.034) + 0.2;                               
            double roundedPPFee = Math.round(paypalFee*100.00)/100.00;                  
            double roundedEbayFee = Math.round(ebayFee*100.00)/100.00;                  
            e4.setText(String.valueOf(roundedEbayFee));                                 
            e5.setText(String.valueOf(roundedPPFee));                                   

        }                                                                               
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (possibly with [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html))

```
    //double yourNumber = ...;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    String roundedValue = df.format(yourNumber);
```

or [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
    //double yourNumber = ...;
    String roundedValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(yourNumber).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).toString();
```

You may want to take a look at [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) where similar question was answered quite extensively.

On a side note, you probably should not store money in a double because of their inability to represent decimal values accurately - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) for broader explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current output you are getting?

Also try this and check your output. Instead of .00, just add .0

```
        double roundedPPFee = Math.round(paypalFee*100.0)/100.0;                  
        double roundedEbayFee = Math.round(ebayFee*100.0)/100.0;
```

Comment: thanks this does work to limit to 2 decimal places, how would i set the output to have 2 decimal places even it is a whole number? for example i want 100 to be displayed as 100.00

Comment: try this .toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

```
        double ebayFee = salePrice / 10.00;
        double paypalFee = (salePrice * 0.034) + 0.2;
        double roundedPPFee = Math.round(paypalFee*100.0)/100.0;
        double roundedEbayFee = Math.round(ebayFee*100.0)/100.0;
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        System.out.println(f.format(roundedPPFee));
        System.out.println(f.format(roundedEbayFee));
```